# How to copy a item from a dictionary to another dictionay?

Tags: c#-4.0, dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> list1= new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
Dictionary<string, List<string>> list2= new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

i want to copy list1's  item in to list2 on the basis of a condition:

```
foreach (var confirmNumber in list1.Keys)
{                                
    if (condition)
    {                                    
        list2.Add(confirmNumber,list1[confirmNumber]);
    }
}
```

it will not actually working.

Comment: Do you have already that second dictionary filled or do you want to create it from the scratch?

Comment: wanna create it from scratch

Answer (score 0):

So you want to take only items from the lists which match a given condition?

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> list2 = list1
    .SelectMany(kv => kv.Value.Select(s => new { kv.Key, s }))
    .Where(x => condition) // you have the key and the string to apply the condition
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => x.s).ToList());
```

Comment: @atulgupta: interesting, a pity that there are no more informations available.